# How do I make a log of my application?

Tags: c#, wpf, logging

How can I make a log of my application? Like maybe when an error is catched, it emails the user a log file? Maybe something like [this](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=332877)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html) is cool

good example to get started: http://sadi02.wordpress.com/2008/06/29/log4net-tutorial-in-c-net-how-can-i-show-log-in-a-file/

Comment: It seems complicated. I downloaded it so is there a dll or something?

Comment: the dll is in \bin\net\2.0\release\log4net.dll

Answer (score 1):

The simple built-in method is to use the `DebugListener` or `TraceListener` and point their output to a log-file.  Of course, log4net offers more options so it's well worth considering too.

Answer (score 0):

Each language tends to have some logging libraries associated with it. sometimes many.

C# and Java have Log4Net and Log4J respectively both under the apache project. Those libraries have been around for a while and have decent tutorials. Python has an excellent logging module built in. In general, google for " logging library" or along those lines.